# LayoutInflater wordSpan

Tags: java, android, html

I want to set wordtoSpan string at OnCreateView.

my code:

```
package com.tachles;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class History_moadim_a extends Fragment {

    TextView horef;
    TextView kaiz;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_moadim_a, container, false);

        return rootView;

        horef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("hgh");
        horef.setText(wordtoSpan);



    }
}
```

Eclipse says that I cant use findViewById, so I tried to insert getView() but still the same problem. Please show me my mistake

Thank you

Comment: please have a look on the answer, hope will help you!!

Comment: the answer is updated, please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `history_moadim_a` is your layout containing the `textView3`, change your `onCreateView()` to something like

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_moadim_a, container, false);

horef = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("hgh");
horef.setText(wordtoSpan);

return rootView;
```

You want to find the `TextView` in the layout you just inflated (`rootView`), and return the layout at the *end* (and not in the middle of the method).

Answer (score 1):

use

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class History_moadim_a extends Fragment {

    TextView horef;
    TextView kaiz;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_moadim_a, container, false);



        horef = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("hgh");
        horef.setText(wordtoSpan);

 return rootView;

    }
}
```

i can not see a return statement at onCreateView at perfect place so please do  `return rootView ;` inside onCreateView at the end of the logics by means at the end of the onCreateView

Comment: you are not returning view perfectly as well please do like return rootView ; at the end of oncreateView

Comment: please return the view as return rootView ;

Comment: `getView()` inside `onCreateView()` won't work - you haven't yet returned the view to the framework it could return with `getView()`.

Comment: Now there's no `findViewById()` in a `Fragment`